# node.js - UnhandledPromiseRejectedWarning: SQLITE_ERROR: table shoes has no column named 'color'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I created a table "shoes" with primary key 'id', and a table "color_shoes" with 'id' from "Shoes" as foreign key, when I tried to post a register to 'color_shoes' using the foreign key in the body of my request, I got this error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectedWarning: SQLITE_ERROR: table shoes has no column named 'color'"

This is the controller function to create a register in the table "color_shoes"

```js
module.exports = {
    async create(request, response) {
        const { color, shoe_id } = request.body;

        const color_id = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('HEX');

        await connection('shoes').insert({
            color_id,
            color,
            shoe_id,
        });

        return response.json({ color_id });
    }
}
```

This is the migration to table "color_shoes":

```js
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('shoes_colors', function (table) {
        table.string('color_id').primary();
        table.string('color').notNullable();

        table.string('shoe_id').notNullable();

        table.foreign('shoe_id').references('id').inTable('shoes');
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('shoes_colors');
};
```

And this is migration to table "shoes":

```js
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('shoes', function (table) {
      table.string('id').primary();
      table.string('model').notNullable();
      table.string('sponsor').notNullable();
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('shoes');
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't `await connection('shoes').insert({` be `await connection('color_shoes').insert({`?

Comment: Thank you. It was a silly error, lol